# Supply ETH to Aave through solidity

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm trying deposit into Aave V2 Contract [Aave's Code Examples](https://github.com/aave/code-examples-protocol/blob/main/V2/Credit%20Delegation/MyV2CreditDelegation.sol)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >= 0.4.22 < 0.8.7;

import { IERC20, ILendingPool, IProtocolDataProvider, IStableDebtToken } from './Interfaces.sol';
import { SafeERC20 } from './Libraries.sol';

/**
* This is a proof of concept starter contract, showing how uncollaterised loans are possible
* using Aave v2 credit delegation.
* This example supports stable interest rate borrows.
* It is not production ready (!). User permissions and user accounting of loans should be implemented.
* See @dev comments
*/

contract MyV2CreditDelegation {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    
    ILendingPool constant lendingPool = ILendingPool(address(0x9FE532197ad76c5a68961439604C037EB79681F0)); // Kovan
    IProtocolDataProvider constant dataProvider = IProtocolDataProvider(address(0x744C1aaA95232EeF8A9994C4E0b3a89659D9AB79)); // Kovan
    
    address owner;

    constructor () public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /**
    * Deposits collateral into the Aave, to enable credit delegation
    * This would be called by the delegator.
    * @param asset The asset to be deposited as collateral
    * @param amount The amount to be deposited as collateral
    * @param isPull Whether to pull the funds from the caller, or use funds sent to this contract
    *  User must have approved this contract to pull funds if `isPull` = true
    * 
    */
    function depositCollateral(address asset, uint256 amount, bool isPull) public {
        if (isPull) {
            IERC20(asset).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        }
        IERC20(asset).safeApprove(address(lendingPool), amount);
        lendingPool.deposit(asset, amount, address(this), 0);
    }

    /**
    * Approves the borrower to take an uncollaterised loan
    * @param borrower The borrower of the funds (i.e. delgatee)
    * @param amount The amount the borrower is allowed to borrow (i.e. their line of credit)
    * @param asset The asset they are allowed to borrow
    * 
    * Add permissions to this call, e.g. only the owner should be able to approve borrowers!
    */
    function approveBorrower(address borrower, uint256 amount, address asset) public {
        (, address stableDebtTokenAddress,) = dataProvider.getReserveTokensAddresses(asset);
        IStableDebtToken(stableDebtTokenAddress).approveDelegation(borrower, amount);
    }
    
    /**
    * Repay an uncollaterised loan
    * @param amount The amount to repay
    * @param asset The asset to be repaid
    * 
    * User calling this function must have approved this contract with an allowance to transfer the tokens
    * 
    * You should keep internal accounting of borrowers, if your contract will have multiple borrowers
    */
    function repayBorrower(uint256 amount, address asset) public {
        IERC20(asset).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        IERC20(asset).safeApprove(address(lendingPool), amount);
        lendingPool.repay(asset, amount, 1, address(this));
    }
    
    /**
    * Withdraw all of a collateral as the underlying asset, if no outstanding loans delegated
    * @param asset The underlying asset to withdraw
    * 
    * Add permissions to this call, e.g. only the owner should be able to withdraw the collateral!
    */
    function withdrawCollateral(address asset) public {
        (address aTokenAddress,,) = dataProvider.getReserveTokensAddresses(asset);
        uint256 assetBalance = IERC20(aTokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
        lendingPool.withdraw(asset, assetBalance, owner);
    }
}
```

I have code which consumes this like so:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},

  init: async function() {
    return await App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: async function() {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
      App.web3Provider = window.ethereum;
      try {
        // Request account access
        await window.ethereum.enable();
      } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
        console.error("User denied account access")
      }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
      App.web3Provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
    }
    // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
    else {
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON('MyV2CreditDelegation.json', function(data) {
      // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with @truffle/contract
      var safeYieldArtifact = data;
      App.contracts.MyV2CreditDelegation = TruffleContract(safeYieldArtifact);
    
      // Set the provider for our contract
      App.contracts.MyV2CreditDelegation.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
    });
    

    

    return App.bindEvents();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-deposit', App.handleDeposit);
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-withdrawl', App.handleWithdrawl);
  },

  handleDeposit: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    
      var account = accounts[0];

      App.contracts.MyV2CreditDelegation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        creditDelegatorInstance = instance;
        const mockETHAddress = "0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE"
        // Execute adopt as a transaction by sending account
        return creditDelegatorInstance.depositCollateral(mockETHAddress, 1, true);
      }).then(function(result) {
        //return App.markAdopted();
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    });
  },

  handleWithdrawl: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  },
};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

When attempting to supply, Metamask displays an error:

> ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.

And just a simple button to call it in html:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-withdrawl" 
  type="button"> Withdrawl
</button>
```

I'm running ganache

`ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{{MyProjectId}}`

The only error I see in the console is:

> Transaction: 0x9961f8a187c09fd7c9ebf803771fa161c9939268bb01552a1598807bcfdc13ff
> Gas usage: 24813
> Block Number: 12905002
> Block Time: Mon Jul 26 2021 20:38:30 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
> Runtime Error: revert

My guess is that I'm not calling the contract from Web3 appropriately

How can programatically supply Eth (Or any other token) to aave?

Comment: Are you sure you're sending it from the right account? After all, I see you defining `account` but never using it.

Comment: good point, I've been playing around with a bunch of different contracts to try to get this to send so that clearly is a bug.  I'll look into it

Comment: Also I noticed that MyV2CreditDelegation refers to a `ILendingPool` and `IProtocolDataProvider` on Kovan, but those addresses aren't in use on mainnet. Since you start ganache by forking mainnet, those wouldn't work. Your `depositCollateral` would definitely fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Hardhat to send transactions instead of Web3 in the browser, but I succeeded:

- I used the Kovan test network.
- I used the [MyCrypto faucet](https://app.mycrypto.com/faucet) to give my test address some ETH.
- I used the [Aave faucet](https://testnet.aave.com/faucet) to give myself some AAVE.
- I imported the contracts from Aave's Code Examples.
- I ran the script below:

Create a new HardHat project

```
npm init --yes
npm install --save-dev hardhat 
npm install @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle 
npm install --save-dev "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@^2.0.0" "ethers@^5.0.0" "ethereum-waffle@^3.2.0"
npx hardhat 
(follow the prompt)
```

```
import '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { LogDescription } from 'ethers/lib/utils';
import hre from 'hardhat';
import { IERC20__factory, MyV2CreditDelegation__factory } from '../typechain';

dotenv.config();

// Infura, Alchemy, ... however you can get access to the Kovan test network
// E.g. https://kovan.infura.io/v3/<project-id>
const KOVAN_JSON_RPC = process.env.KOVAN_JSON_RPC || '';
if (!KOVAN_JSON_RPC) {
    console.error('Forgot to set KOVAN_JSON_RPC in aave.ts or .env');
    process.exit(1);
}

// Test account that has Kovan ETH and an AAVE token balance
const AAVE_HOLDER = '';

async function main() {
    // Fork Kovan
    await hre.network.provider.request({
        method: 'hardhat_reset',
        params: [{ forking: { jsonRpcUrl: KOVAN_JSON_RPC } }],
    });

    // Act like AAVE_HOLDER
    await hre.network.provider.request({
        method: 'hardhat_impersonateAccount',
        params: [AAVE_HOLDER],
    });
    const signer = await hre.ethers.getSigner(AAVE_HOLDER);
    console.log('signer:', signer.address);

    // AAVE token on Kovan network
    const token = IERC20__factory.connect('0xb597cd8d3217ea6477232f9217fa70837ff667af', signer);
    console.log('token balance:', (await token.balanceOf(signer.address)).toString());

    const MyV2CreditDelegation = new MyV2CreditDelegation__factory(signer);
    const delegation = await MyV2CreditDelegation.deploy({ gasLimit: 1e7 });
    console.log('delegation:', delegation.address);

    await token.approve(delegation.address, 1000000000000);
    console.log('allowance:', (await token.allowance(signer.address, delegation.address, { gasLimit: 1e6 })).toString());

    const depositTrans = await delegation.depositCollateral(token.address, 1000000000000, true, { gasLimit: 1e6 });
    console.log('depositTrans:', depositTrans.hash);
    const receipt = await depositTrans.wait();
    for (const log of receipt.logs) {
        const [name, desc] = parseLog(log) || [];
        if (desc) {
            const args = desc.eventFragment.inputs.map(({ name, type, indexed }, index) =>
                `\n    ${type}${indexed ? ' indexed' : ''} ${name}: ${desc.args[name]}`);
            args.unshift(`\n    contract ${name} ${log.address}`);
            console.log('Event', log.logIndex, `${desc.name}(${args ? args.join(',') : ''})`);
        } else {
            console.log('Log', log.logIndex, JSON.stringify(log.topics, null, 4), JSON.stringify(log.data));
        }
    }

    function parseLog(log: { address: string, topics: Array<string>, data: string }): [string, LogDescription] | undefined {
        try { return ['', delegation.interface.parseLog(log)]; } catch (e) { }
        try {
            const desc = token.interface.parseLog(log);
            return [log.address.toLowerCase() === token.address.toLowerCase() ? 'AAVE' : 'IERC20', desc];
        } catch (e) { }
    }
}

main().then(() => process.exit(0), error => {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    console.error(error);
});
```

With as result:

```
$ hardhat run --no-compile --network kovan .\scripts\Aave.ts
token balance: 999999000000000000
delegation: 0x2863E2a95Dc84C227B11CF1997e295E59ab15670
allowance: 1000000000000
depositTrans: 0x0a3d1a8bfbdfc0f403371f9936122d19bdc9f3539c34e3fb1b0a7896a398f923
Done in 57.11s.
```

Which you can verify on [Etherscan for Kovan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xA9B62C680C945397dC23fc15D66460D48005D4E1) (blocks 26666177, 26666180 and 26666183):

- Deploying `MyV2CreditDelegation` ([transaction](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x9a1a4bf8b1718d1cba63697331ff5e98d4654ca5a3a6af43326071907d75a8cd), [contract](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x2863e2a95dc84c227b11cf1997e295e59ab15670))
- Approving contract for AAVE ([transaction](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xee84ae70848bdc76c4dc448447837ea12945dabe90323a3f45df37ba8c3a10ae))

  - Logged `Approval` event and `token.allowance` returned correct value
- Depositing collateral ([transaction](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x0a3d1a8bfbdfc0f403371f9936122d19bdc9f3539c34e3fb1b0a7896a398f923))

  - Transferred `0.000001` AAVE from my address to deployed contract
  - Transferred `0.000001` aAAVE from my address to deployed contract
  - Transferred `0.000001` AAVE from deployed contract to `aAAVE` contract
  - Bunch of logged events for Transfer/Approval/Mint/DelegatedPowerChanged/...

Originally my script would first deploy a test token (and mint me some balance on it) which I would try to deposit as collateral, but the provider somehow reverted it without a transaction even showing up on Kovan Etherscan. The issue in your code might thus be the `mockETHAddress`, as well as it seems like you're not actually approving your delegation contract to withdraw the specified amount.

A more complex but ready-to-run setup is available in [this repository](https://github.com/SchoofsKelvin/aave-test). It impersonates an account that has an ETH and AAVE balance on Kovan.

Comment: This answer is still lacking a bit.  I've tried to update your answer to make it more noob proof.  However, when I try to `run hardhat run --no-compile --network kovan .\scripts\Aave.ts`  I get an error ` Cannot use import statement outside a module`  Please update the answer to include how to setup the project appropriately

Comment: Honestly this answer could use some improvement, but I won't have the bounty go to waste, please update this answer

Comment: can you provide a git repo?

Comment: Work aside, took me a bit to extract the script and dependencies, but I added a [demo repository](https://github.com/SchoofsKelvin/aave-test) which should only require you to do `yarn; yarn build; yarn start;` to see the script work. _Assuming you got Yarn v1.22.0+ installed._ Hopefully that works for you?

Comment: Not sure if you have time,  but I created [seperate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68766559/1938988) for withdrawl, I thought it would be straight forward from here but the transaction gets reverted

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for how to integrate with Aave V3 in a Solidity contract, here is an example.

The following is a simple smart contract that allows you to supply Aave with ERC20 token collateral, and take out a variable rate loan.

This is how you can test the smart contract:

1. Obtain test USDC from [Aave's faucet](https://app.aave.com/faucet/) (make sure your wallet is on the Goerli network).
2. Deploy this smart contract to the Goerli network.
3. Send some of the test USDC to the address of the contract you just deployed.
4. Call the supply() function.
5. Call the borrow() function.

```
// contracts/AaveExample.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "@aave-protocol/interfaces/IPool.sol";
import "@openzeppelin-contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Aave {

    // Storage Variables
    address public borrowTokenAddress = 0xDF1742fE5b0bFc12331D8EAec6b478DfDbD31464; // Goerli Aave DAI
    address public supplyTokenAddress = 0xA2025B15a1757311bfD68cb14eaeFCc237AF5b43; // Goerli Aave USDC
    address public aavePoolAddress = 0x368EedF3f56ad10b9bC57eed4Dac65B26Bb667f6;    // Goerli Aave Pool Address


    constructor() {}
    
    function supply() public returns (bool) {
        // 1. Set amountToDrain to the contract's supplyTokenAddress balance
        uint amountToDrain = IERC20(supplyTokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));

        // 2. Approve Aave pool to access amountToDrain from this contract 
        IERC20(supplyTokenAddress).approve(aavePoolAddress, amountToDrain);

        // 3. Supply amountToDrain to Aave pool
        IPool(aavePoolAddress).supply(supplyTokenAddress, amountToDrain, address(this), 0);

        return true;
    }

    function borrow() public returns (bool) {
        // Borrow 0.3 DAI
        IPool(aavePoolAddress).borrow(borrowTokenAddress, 0.3 ether, 2, 0, address(this));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just lend / supply ETH to the Aave lending pool using Solidity then there's a better way to do it.
Aave has a [WETH Gateway](https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/the-core-protocol/weth-gateway) that automatically converts ETH to WETH and WETH to ETH when you want to withdraw.
You will need the WETH gateway interface, IERC20 interface and aWETH (Aave interest bearing tokens) interface to make it work.
The purpose of aWeth tokens is to keep track of the funds you have supplied to the lending pool. They get burnt by the WETH gateway when you call the **withdrawETH()** function on the WETH gateway.
I've written a detailed [guide](https://www.helpmegeek.com/how-to-earn-yield-contract-aave/) on how to do it.